# Cisco ASA Becomes Non-responsive

Tags: cisco-asa, diagnostic

I have a client that has a Cisco ASA 5505 that sits between their router (provides VOIP phone service) and their Cisco 3550 (Very old version of IOS) that they use as a "Core" switch. This works well most of the time. However, every few months, the ASA will become completely non-responsive, and the client loses interent and VPN access.

I am normally able to resolve this by bouncing the switch port on the 3550, but this did not work yesterday, and I had to get someone to power cycle the ASA. I work remotely most days, so I never seem to be on site when this happens.

I need to figure out a way to diagnose this problem, but the ASA doesn't seem to be logging anything during/before the problem occurs. Not to mention, a power cycle clears out the log buffer, so if that happens, I get nothing.

I am on site today, so I am hoping to take a look at this and at least take some initial diagnostic steps. Does anyone have a suggestion for logs that I can turn on, or other things to check that could cause this behavior?

I don't have SmartNet right now, but I am getting approval to purchase it if needed, but that won't be helpful for today.

Thanks.

Edit, add IOS versions:
ASA 5505:
Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 7.2(4) 
Device Manager Version 5.2(4)

Cisco 3550:
Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software 
IOS (tm) C3550 Software (C3550-I5Q3L2-M), Version 12.1(9)EA1c, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Comment: What version of the ASA operating system are you on?

Comment: Added above: ASA 5505: Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 7.2(4) Device Manager Version 5.2(4)

Cisco 3550: Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software IOS (tm) C3550 Software (C3550-I5Q3L2-M), Version 12.1(9)EA1c, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Answer (score 1):

That is a very, very old ASA OS version.

Let's assume for a moment the switch is not involved; it would take an astronomically remote combination of factors and network data to bring down a device which is intended **specifically** to withstand outside network attacks (i.e., a firewall.)

[**Logging is trivially enabled on the ASA**](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a00805a2e04.shtml); configure a syslog server to capture everything to an external location.

The log results are also explained in full in the Cisco documentation; if in doubt, return here with more useful information.

Comment: Thanks. I set up a syslog server, and have pointed the ASA to it. I guess now we just wait for it to happen again, and see if anything interesting shows up in the logs. Thank you.